# getting error while launching Jmeter 2.9

Tags: jmeter

getting below error while launching `JMeter.bat` file from

> C:\Program Files\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin

I have set JAVA_HOME as below:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1 Press
>   any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally downloaded the source distribution or there was an error unpacking the downloaded archive.

Make sure there's `ApacheJMeter.jar` in the JMeter `bin` folder. Also, there should be dozens of JAR files in the JMeter `lib` folder.